How can I create a reusable LineChart component that sometimes adds a gradient fill using vue-chartjs v5?
I'm currently trying to build a flexible, reusable line chart component using vue-chartjs v5. It's working well so far, but I've struggled mightily to get a gradient fill working on it. I've found many similar questions online, but none that address my specific use case, and I frequently run into answers that are written for v3 or v4. Here's what I have so far:
LineChart.vue source code:
<template>
    <Line 
        :options="chartOptions"
        :data="chartData"
    />
</template>

<script>
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'
import {Chart as ChartJS, CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend, Filler } from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend, Filler)

export default {
    name: 'LineChart',
    components: { Line },
    props: {
        chartData: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
        chartOptions: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => {}
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log($this.refs)
        if (this.$refs.gradientChart) {
            const ctx = this.$refs.gradientChart.getContext('2d')
            const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 450)
            gradient.addColorStop(0, '#7d9beb')
            gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)')

            //In this case, I know that I'll only ever have one dataset
            this.chartData.datasets[0].backgroundColor = gradient;

            this.renderChart(this.chartOptions, this.chartData)
        }
    }
}
</script>

App.vue source code:
<template>
    <LineChart id="gradient-chart" ref="gradientChart" :chartOptions="gradientChartOptions" :chartData="gradientChartData"/>
    <LineChart id="non-gradient-line-chart" :chartData="nonGradientChartData" :chartOptions="nonGradientChartOptions"/>
</template>

<script setup>
//Script code goes here, including definitions for gradientChartOptions, gradientChartData, nonGradientChartOptions, and nonGradientChartData
</script>

With all of this, I'm running into 2 problems:

According to the documentation I found at https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#access-to-chart-instance, I should be able to access the chart instance by putting a ref attribute on my parent, then using this.$refs. in my child component. I'm very likely missing something obvious, but this isn't working as expected.

The pattern of using mounted() { ...this.renderChart() } seems to have been deprecated in v4, and was replaced by using the data() method instead. I've found plenty of documentation on this online, but all of documentation I've seen involved hardcoding the chart options and data in the child component, and I haven't found an example that mixes the passing of props with the data() pattern.


Any help I could get with this would be sincerely appreciated. Thanks!
